# installing same R packages into R studiio

Tags: r, rstudio

Do I need to install same r packages which i have already installed into my R environment to RStudio environment. As I recall with our new version of R we cannot run RStudio and duplicating same installation of R packages twice into R and RStudio is troublesome too. Does anybody have idea of eliminating the problem of repeating the installation process in these two software environment?

Answer (score 1):

RStudio is just an IDE, i.e. a development environment. It does not replace R. You have to link your R version to RStudio.

To do that, follow these simple steps:

- In Rstudio, click on "Tools/Options..."
- In the newly opened window, click on "Change" (first line)
- If your R version appears in the list, click on it. Otherwise, browse the folder where your version is.

Once you have linked RStudio to the R version you use, you can use it with RStudio and all your packages ar available as if you used R through the command line  or th RGui (in Windows).